# Not getting exception while passing invalid json request body to rest api in spring boot

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have created one rest API in spring-boot, the problem is that I am taking 4 parameters as a requestbody argument as a JSON object.

Now if I pass the JSON object with 5 parameters than my API still call, no assertion exception occurs while serializing the JSON object.
I have one dto class as below with constructor

```
public class testDto{
   @NotNull(message = "fistName can not be null.")
   private String fistName;
   @NotNull(message = "lastName can not be null.")
   private String lastName;
   private String nickName;

   public testDto() {
    }

    public testDto(@NotNull(message = "fistName can not be null.") final String fistName ,@NotNull(message = "lastName can not be null.") final String lastName , final String nickName){
      super();
      this.fistName = fistName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
      this.nickName = nickName;
    }
}
```

**My restapi** as below,

```
@PostMapping(path ={ "/api/v1/user"}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> saveUser(
            @Valid @RequestBody(required = true) final testDto dto) throws Exception {
}
```

Now while calling my API I am **passing request body** as below

```
{
      "fistName" : "abc",
      "lastName" : "xyz",
      "nickName" : "pqr",
      "age" : 25
}
```

Now here when I pass `age` parameter and call the API, my API still working instead of throwing an exception for No any constructor found as I have passed age which is not a member of my dto class.

**Expected result:** don't allow to call API
**Actual result:** Allow me to call API

**I have also tried** with assertion exception declaration and binding exception but not getting any success.

also set the property

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.resources.add-mappings=false
```

Comment: Have you configured `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver`?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot uses Jackson to map the JSON payload to an instance of your `testDto` class. By default, Jackson is [configured to ignore entries in the JSON that it cannot map to the DTO](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper). This follows the [robustness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) or Postel's law as it's also known.

You can configure Jackson to fail when it cannot map an entry in the JSON to a property on a DTO by adding the following line to your application's `application.properties` file in `src/main/resources`:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true
```

Comment: Hi Andy,
it works fine, Thank you for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

What to do when the request is invalid json but the values are correct ex:

```
{
      "fistName" : "abc",
      "lastName" : "xyz",
      "nickName" : "pqr",
      "nickName" : "pqrs"
}
```

Now in this case it is taking the last one and mapping it